# Accessing R.raw resources in Android Instrumentation jUnit test

Tags: android, junit, android-resources

I'm trying to make some Android Instrumentation classes in Android Studio so that I can test my ormlite classes. The `DBHelper` class for ormlite requires reading from the ormlite config file, which is in my `res/raw/ormlite_config.txt` and accessed using `R.raw.ormlite_config`.

It's not something that I use `openRawResource(R.raw.ormlite_config)` to get, because the constructor for the DBHelper's superclass wants the int resource.

When I run my test, it can't find it though:

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090001`

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090001
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1181)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1158)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.openFileId(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:310)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.<init>(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:76)
at com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.DB.<init>(DB.java:40)
at com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.DB.shared(DB.java:31)
at com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.ORMLiteTest.setup(ORMLiteTest.java:29)
...
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)

Tests ran to completion.
```

The DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }
}
```

My jUnit test case:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ORMLiteTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        DB.shared(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext());
    }
}
```

FIXED with Commonsware's answer:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ORMLiteTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        DB.shared(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`getContext()` returns a `Context` pointing to resources from your `androidTest/` source set. Use `getTargetContext()` if the resources are in the actual app itself (e.g., `main/` source set).